# spring-boot-thin-launcher produces jar with dependencies instead

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, maven, jar

I am trying to use the  spring-boot-thin-launcher in a Kotlin/Maven build and instead of a tinny jar I get a complete jar with dependencies, just as it normally builds so far.

I can showcase the important bits of the `pom.xml` but probably it is not practical to include the whole pom.

```xml
...
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.5</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
...
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- The following enables the "thin jar" deployment option. -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot.experimental</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-thin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${thin.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
...
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot.experimental</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-thin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${thin.version}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <!-- Download the dependencies at build time -->
            <id>resolve</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>resolve</goal>
            </goals>
            <inherited>false</inherited>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

And these are the logs after cleaning and packaging with maven:

```
❯ mvn -Dmaven.test.skip=true package
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] -----------------------< org.xyz:someproject >------------------------
[INFO] Building xyz someproject 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO]   from pom.xml
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- jacoco:0.8.7:prepare-agent (pre-unit-test) @ someproject ---
[INFO] surefireArgLine set to -javaagent:/Users/the-user/.m2/repository/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/0.8.7/org.jacoco.agent-0.8.7-runtime.jar=destfile=/Users/the-user/projects/someproject/target/coverage-reports/jacoco-ut.exec
[INFO]
[INFO] --- resources:3.2.0:resources (default-resources) @ someproject ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered properties files.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 22 resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- compiler:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ someproject ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- kotlin:1.7.0:compile (compile) @ someproject ---
[INFO] Applied plugin: 'spring'
[INFO]
[INFO] --- resources:3.2.0:testResources (default-testResources) @ someproject ---
[INFO] Not copying test resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- compiler:3.8.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ someproject ---
[INFO] Not compiling test sources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- kotlin:1.7.0:test-compile (test-compile) @ someproject ---
[INFO] Test compilation is skipped
[INFO]
[INFO] --- surefire:2.22.2:test (default-test) @ someproject ---
[INFO] Tests are skipped.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- jacoco:0.8.7:report (post-unit-test) @ someproject ---
[INFO] Skipping JaCoCo execution due to missing execution data file.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- jar:3.2.0:jar (default-jar) @ someproject ---
[INFO] Building jar: /Users/the-user/projects/someproject/target/someproject-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO]
[INFO] --- spring-boot:2.5.5:repackage (repackage) @ someproject ---
[INFO] Replacing main artifact with repackaged archive
[INFO]
[INFO] --- spring-boot-thin:1.0.31.RELEASE:resolve (resolve) @ someproject ---
[INFO] Deploying: /Users/the-user/projects/someproject/target/someproject-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] Copying: someproject-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar to /Users/the-user/projects/someproject/target/thin/root
[INFO] All deployables and dependencies ready in: /Users/the-user/projects/someproject/target/thin/root
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  50.454 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2024-01-18T14:28:16Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I'm afraid that somehow the `spring-boot-thin-maven-plugin` within `spring-boot-maven-plugin` does not actually kick in but I cannot figure out why and how to fix this. Any ideas?